# Spinner value is not captured

Tags: java, android

**Please, do not mark this as duplicate if you are not sure**

I have three spinners and a botton. When the botton is clicked, the program makes a calculation depending on the value of the three spinners. Then this value passes two another activity and it shows in an editText. Here is my code:

**Main**

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        capturarTexto();
    }


    private void capturarTexto() {
        Button button_calc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_calc);
        button_calc.setOnClickListener(get_edit_view_button_listener);
    }

    private Button.OnClickListener get_edit_view_button_listener = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText edit_text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox1);
            String edit_text_value = edit_text.getText().toString();
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(edit_text_value);
            int num_words = st.countTokens();
            Spinner espec = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.espec);
            String espec_value = espec.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Spinner lengor = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_origen);
            String lengor_value = lengor.getSelectedItem().toString();
            Spinner lengdest = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.lista_destino);
            String lengdest_value = lengdest.getSelectedItem().toString();
            double precio = 0;
            if(espec_value .equals("Medicina")){
            if (lengor_value .equals("ES") && lengdest_value .equals("EN")){
                precio = num_words * 0.12;
            }
            if (lengor_value .equals("ES") && lengdest_value .equals("FR")){
                precio = num_words * 0.12;
            }
            if (lengor_value .equals("ES") && lengdest_value .equals("DE")){
                precio = num_words * 0.12;
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main3Activity.class);
            intent.putExtra("precio",precio);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };

}
```

**Main2**

```
public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

        Intent intent=getIntent();
        int precio =(int) intent.getExtras().getInt("precio");
        TextView txtCambio = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        txtCambio.setText("Precio Total: "+ precio + " €");
    }
```

After testing it, the value passed in this line of code:

```
intent.putExtra("precio",precio)
```

is allways 0. But if I change it to this:

```
intent.putExtra("precio",num_words)
```

it passes correctly the total number of words. This makes me think that the script is not entering in the first `if(espec_value .equals("Medicina"))` and then, it is not making any calculation.

Does anyone have an idea of how to solve this problem?

Thank you for your time

Comment: where is `num_pal ` ?

Comment: you have not taken "num_pal" anywhere so check that

Comment: Sorry, num_pal is num_words translated from spanish. I tried to do it more understandable for english speakers

Comment: @alberzyzz: try to use String.contains or String.equalsignorecase instead of equals

Comment: you are sending Double value via intent, but in Main3Activity you are accessing Integer value - `int precio =(int) intent.getExtras().getInt("precio");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending `Double` value and accessing `Integer` value.
Change the line in Main3Activity.

```
double precio = intent.getExtras().getDouble("precio");
```

If you want to parse double value to int then add one more line

```
int p = (int) precio;
```